# Refractoring code: private variables

Tags: php

I have to refractor a lot of code and there are a few design issues that I've been running into over and over again and I can't decide what would be better:

```
class LintRequestDispatcher {

  private $_info;
  private $_build_log;
  private $_results;

  public function __construct($info, $build_log) {
    $this->_info = $info;
    $this->_build_log = $build_log;
  }

  public function processLog() {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($this->_build_log);
    $lines = explode("\n", $file_contents);
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
      if (preg_match('/^.+=.+ in (.+) on line (\d+)$/', $line, $tokens)) {
        $errors[] = array('file' => $tokens[1] , 'line_number' => $tokens[2], 'message' => $tokens[0]);
      }
    }

    $arr = array('job_name' => $this->_info['job_name'], 'build_number' => $this->_info['build_number'], 'errors' => $errors);
    $this->_results = $arr;
  }

  public function post(Client $client) {
    $request = $client->createRequest(
        'POST',
        '/app.php/api/reports/lint',
        array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
        json_encode($this->_results)
    );

    $request->send();
  }
}
```

1. Should the variables `$info`, `$build_log` be passed in through the constructor and stored as private variables (and there might be getter/setter methods to access the variables) or should it just be passed in to the functions that use it?  The only function that uses this in this case is `processLog()`.  I felt that passing the variables through the constructor and storing the variables is unnecessary.
2. Should `processLog()` and `post()` be combined into 1 function? `processLog()` stores results in `$_results` private variable and then `post()` is called afterwards to use it..  But it might be hard to unit test?
3. Should these be issues to worry about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If I was using a class as a container to group functions together (in stead of using it as a definition of a full blown object) I'd prefer passing in the variables and not storing them as members.
2. You could combine them into one function, if you're positive that the result of `processLog()` will only ever be used as input into `post()`.
3. Whether you should worry about this depends on a couple of other things. Are you working as part of a team? Will this code be maintained by someone else? Are you sure that the code will always be called in the correct order (even in multi-threaded environments)? Will you be instantiating one object of type `LintRequestDispatcher` and reuse it? It isn't the best approach, but if you're trying to hack something together real quick than I wouldn't worry about it. If this is part of some bigger project, I'd recommend splitting off the parser into its own class.

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion:

1. If you want to use constructor you can use bellow code, because the variables only be use on specific function. Or if you don't want to use the constructor just move the parameters to `processLog()` and no need for `$_info` and `$_build_log`. For performance I suggest the second one.

   ```
   class LintRequestDispatcher {

       private $_info;
       private $_build_log;
       private $_results;

       public function __construct($info = null, $build_log = null) {
           $this->_info = $info;
           $this->_build_log = $build_log;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Based on suggestion from no. 1, it's better to combine both function. But if you want to be able unit test both of the function, just put the `post()` function into `processLog()`

   ```
   public function processLog(Client $client, $info, $build_log) {
       $file_contents = file_get_contents($build_log);
       $lines = explode("\n", $file_contents);
       $errors = array();
       foreach ($lines as $line) {
           if (preg_match('/^.+=.+ in (.+) on line (\d+)$/', $line, $tokens)) {
               $errors[] = array('file' => $tokens[1] , 'line_number' => $tokens[2], 'message' => $tokens[0]);
           }
       }

       $arr = array('job_name' => $info['job_name'], 'build_number' => $info['build_number'], 'errors' => $errors);
       $this->post($client, $arr);
   }

   public function post(Client $client, $results) {
       $request = $client->createRequest(
           'POST',
           '/app.php/api/reports/lint',
           array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
           json_encode($results)
       );

      $request->send();
   }
   ```
3. I don't think those are critical issues, but considering to add some validation on `processLog()`. You don't really know what is the input are, it can be an empty string or  maybe wrong file name/path.